# Where can I find the rules about when I should vs. should not comment?

Tags: support, comments

I am very new to Stack Exchange. Several times, my comments have been deleted. I really feel bad; I hope I am not setting a bad impression because I am ignoring some rule that I must have missed about what counts as a good comment. I have read the site tour.

Occasionally I indulge in a "great answer!" type comment. Sometimes it gets deleted; sometimes not. Are such comments forbidden? Is there any "recommended" way to give compliments to people?

Sometimes I try to respond productively, asking a question on the question/answer or bringing some extra cases, and sometimes those get deleted too. I get this feeling I must have said something really stupid, so firstly, let me apologise. I'm new and learning. Sometimes I'm not sure...

Could someone point me to the right place for further reading so I don't have to keep giving you guys extra moderation work? Thank you, and apologies again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically speaking, these comments are discouraged on Stack Exchange sites. Quoting from [the help center](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers):

> **Please do *not* add a comment on your question or on an answer to say "Thank you".** Comments are meant for requesting clarification, leaving constructive criticism, or adding relevant but minor additional information – not for socializing. If you want to say "thank you," vote on or accept that person's answer, or simply pay it forward by providing a great answer to someone else's question.

Some sites enforce this policy in a more machmir (stringent) way, others are more lenient. Mi Yodeya isn't the strictest when it comes to comments, in my experience, but thank-you comments are still generally discouraged, and can be flagged as "no longer needed" if you see them.

Comment: Thanks. Is there anywhere else I can find further information about what does and doesn't count as a valid comment?

Comment: @RabbiKaii Here is one place https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment and here is another https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756/166155

Comment: @DoubleAA perfect, thanks!